# How to get resolved value/rejected error in finally block?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, q

Using the Q.js Javascript promise library, how can I get the resolved value/rejected error object in the finally block. Basically I want to execute common code in the finally block with the resolved data which was passed to the then block.

```js
var q = require('Q');

var defer = q.defer();

setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("----------------------------------");

    promise2 = defer.promise;
    var t = promise2.then(function (value) {
        console.log('defer then => ' + value);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('defer catch => ' + err);
    })
    .finally(function (data) {
        console.log('function pro1 : ' + defer);
        // console.log('defer finally(resolved value) => ' + data); // how to get 123 here
        // console.log('defer finally(error) => ' + data); // how to get 'Error occurred.' here
        doSomething(data);
    })

    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('after2: ' + t);
    },2000)

    defer.resolve('123');
    defer.reject('Error occurred.');
},10);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The finally is a function used to execute code regardless of the resolution or rejection of a promise, code such as cleaning resources (closing connections, etc). So it is not a good idea to use it for a case where you need the data. Also, I don't suggest the use of global variable, since this does not follow much the idea of the Promise.

If you need both the value in case the Promise succeed or fails, I suggest using a sequence of `then`, `catch` and `then`, like this:

```
var q = require('Q');

var defer = q.defer();

setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("----------------------------------");

    promise2 = defer.promise;
    var t = promise2.then(function (value) {
        console.log('defer then => ' + value);
        return { status: "success", value: value };
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('defer catch => ' + err);
        return { status: "err", value: err };
    })
    .then(function (dataOrError) {
        console.log('function pro1 : ' + defer);
        // console.log('defer finally(resolved value) => ' + data); // how to get 123 here
        // console.log('defer finally(error) => ' + data); // how to get 'Error occurred.' here
        doSomething(dataOrError); // Here you can check if you got an error or the value you exepected.
    })

    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('after2: ' + t);
    },2000)

    defer.resolve('123');
    defer.reject('Error occurred.');
},10);
```

But, if you are going to execute code, depending on the result of you promise (resolved or rejected), you should use this pattern:

```
promise.then((data) => {
   //doSomething with data
   return data;
 }).catch((err) => {
   //doSomithing with error
   return error;
 }).then((dataOrError) => {
  //doSomething with dataOrErro that does not depend if it is data or error
 });
```

Comment: clean solution and well explained

Answer (score 0):

You can add a variable in the parent scope, like this :

```js
var q = require('Q');

var defer = q.defer();

setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("----------------------------------");

    var promise2 = defer.promise;
    var data = false;
    var t = promise2.then(function (value) {
        console.log('defer then => ' + value);
        data  = value;
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('defer catch => ' + err);
    })
    .finally(function () {
        console.log('function pro1 : ' + defer);
        // console.log('defer finally(resolved value) => ' + data); // how to get 123 here
        // console.log('defer finally(error) => ' + data); // how to get 'Error occurred.' here
        doSomething(data);
    })

    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('after2: ' + t);
    },2000)

    defer.resolve('123');
    defer.reject('Error occurred.');
},10);
```

Comment: This does not work, as it does not wait for the promise to get resolved.

Comment: That is the simple way but may not work with more complex promise method chaining. Also I'm looking for a more elegant solution without having to declare a variable in the parent scope - it makes the code more difficult to comprehend.

Answer (score 0):

use `await` and a global variable. Wait till promise gets resolved and then assign the retrieved value to the global variable, which then you can access in the `final` block.

```js
const func = () => new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve(10);
});

let data;

(async() => {
    try {
        data = await func();
    }
    catch(e) {
      // ..
    }
    finally {
        console.log(data);
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with a modern **async/await** syntax, I solved this is by creating a wrapper function around my async method and handle the result in the wrapper function.

(As other answers mentioned, the `finally` is used for cleanup and not for handling the awaited result).

So, this code (old):

```
export async function doAsync(): Promise<string> {
  try {
    if (...) {
      return Promise.resolve("hello");
    }
    if (...) {
      return Promise.resolve("world");
    }
    if (...) {
      return Promise.reject("error");
    }
  } finally {
    console.log("doAsync complete");
  }
}
```

Was changed to this code (new):

```
async function _doAsync(): Promise<string> {
    if (...) {
      return Promise.resolve("hello");
    }
    if (...) {
      return Promise.resolve("world");
    }
    if (...) {
      return Promise.reject("error");
    }
  }
}
export async function doAsync(): Promise<string> {
  try {
    const result = await _doAsync();
    console.log("doAsync complete with result: ", result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("doAsync failed with error: ", error);
  } finally {
    // keep this block for some cleanup if need it
  }
}
```

PS. Notice we only exporting the `doAsync` wrapper and keep the `_doAsync` as private/internal method.